# How to check line feed(&#10) after</Underline>Tag and need to replace with to <br/> tag in xslt code

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I have XML file need to convert into HTML using XSLT Code

Please Refer XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Lesson><Title>Merged Words_G1L5</Title><IntroBlock><ParaBlock><RichText>Materials: Exercise books and pencils</RichText></ParaBlock></IntroBlock><Topic><Title>Underlines – 15 minutes</Title><ParaBlock><CustomNote><SimpleBlock><RichText>
<Underline>ACHIEVE</Underline>
Fill in the Blank: go, wear, quiet, bus, I
1. the pupils are _____.
2. My parents are _____.
3. This school is a _____.
4. ____ am very tall.
5. They _____ sandals.</RichText></SimpleBlock></CustomNote></ParaBlock></Topic></Lesson>
```

**Normally line feed(&#10) is converted into `<br/>` tag from my existing code**

**Existing Code :
1. When Check Line Feed and replace with `<br/>` tag:**

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
            <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

            <xsl:variable name="starttext" select="substring-before(concat($text,'&#10;'),'&#10;')" />
            <xsl:variable name="nexttext" select="substring-after($text,'&#10;')"/>

            <xsl:if test="normalize-space($starttext)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$starttext"/>
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space($nexttext)">
                    <br />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text,'&#10;')">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$nexttext"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
```

**Existing Code: 2. Related To Underline:**

```
<xsl:template match="Underline">
        <xsl:if test="text() or *">
            <u>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </u>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Existing Code : 3. Related To Rich Text:**

```
<xsl:template match="RichText">
    <xsl:if test="text() or *">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

The above mention is my existing code.
**I need a solution for How to check Line Feed(&#10) when is come after `</Underline>` tag and `</UnderLine>` Tag under the `<RichText>`, Because normal scenario is my code working fine, but is causing only when `</UnderLine>` tag come under the `<RichText>`
anyone, please suggest how to I Check Line Feed(&#10) after `</UnderLine>` tag in my Code
?????.**

**Current Issue:**
[Current Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXKrv.png)

---

**Required Output:**
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzTTG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting a `<br />` under the condition of:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($starttext)">
```

This condition is not true when the text starts with a line-feed - as it does in your example. If you want to preserve the opening line-feed, remove the condition.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, if i remove this condition then how to manage this situation - "when the text starts with a line-feed" Any specific solution for How I check "</Underline> tag come under <RichText> tag and linefeed after </Underline> , can you please suggest ?

Comment: A line-feed after `Underline` already exists. You are the one removing it.

Comment: Thanks, Michael for the suggestion, Any idea how I check </UnderLine>&#10 in if condition and &#10 replace to '<br/>'. Because I need to check specifically this thing please suggest? and sequence of code also? 
I am very new with XSLT code Please help out me...

Comment: We seem to be going in a circle.

Comment: Because I need to check both conditions in the same code, some files need this code and some other files have </UnderLine>&#10 conditions, but the first condition overwrites to second one. How I manage both in the same code.